# ¿Cómo importar un modulo de otro paquete desde un modulo entre un paquete que está al mismo nivel?

Tags: python-3.x

estoy intentando importar un modulo de constantes desde un paquete que se encuentra al mismo nivel del paquete que almacena el modulo constantes.py, mi duda es, si es esto posible en python y si se puede lograr empleando import o from, o cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo. La idea es poder acceder al archivo de constantes desde varios módulos sin que sea necesario replicarlo en el directorio actual.

mis carpetas están organizadas de la siguiente forma:

proyecto

```
funcion_uno

   - archivo_uno.py

funcion_dos

   - archivo_dos.py

constantes

   - constantes.py
```

la idea es poder hacer uso del módulo de constantes desde los módulos archivo_uno.py y archivo_dos.py

Ejemplo:

Constantes.py

```
NOMBRE = "Un nombre cualquiera"
```

---

archivo_uno.py

```
from ..constantes.constantes import NOMBRE

print("Hola {}".format(NOMBRE))
```

---

archivo_dos.py

```
from ..constantes.constantes import NOMBRE

print("Adiós {}".format(NOMBRE))
```

---

El punto es que utilizando la ruta relativa con los dos puntos como lo tengo me arroja un error y si intento usar import ni siquiera reconoce el paquete contantes, tener en cuenta que ya cree el archivo **init**.py pero aun así no funcionó. Según leí en otra pregunta se debe a que la ruta de importación no depende del orden de los directorios en el disco sino de la lista de rutas almacenadas en la variable path. Finalmente agradezco a quien pueda responder esta pregunta o sugerir una mejor forma de compartir el acceso a constantes desde diferentes módulos.

Comment: crea un `__init__.py` que haga los import necesarios

Comment: Hola Christian buena tarde gracias por la respuesta; pero me gustaría si es posible, me indicara la ubicación del archivo __init__.py o si hay algún recurso en internet que pudiera citar en el que se indique la forma en la que se debe hacer, ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con este lenguaje de programación.

Comment: puedes leer [esto](https://pythondiario.com/2013/06/initpy-en-python-que-es-y-como-funciona.html)